# Read PHP Session cookies from subdomains as well as from domain?

Tags: php, session

I added `php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com` to my .htaccess in order to be able to read PHP cookie from all subdomains, it seems to work however I cannot read the cookie when I am at: 'example.com' (no subdomains).

This is driving me crazy, I'm sure it's a common issue since most people want their users to be logged in both the domain and all subdomains once they are authenticated.

What can I do to be able to write/read php cookie from any domain/subdomain?

Comment: What browsers did you test this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no dependable way of doing this with session variables. You can either change your root domain to `www.example.com` or use cookies.

The docs for PHP's setcookie say Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'.

Comment: I tried that, It just make the cookie work as it regularly does. (only work in main domain)

Comment: considering there is not initial dot in example.com, this rule obviously couldn't work. maybe send all traffic to www.example.com?

Comment: I'll take it into account but right now all my site is sans www. so adding it now would be bad for seo. No solution that works in both cases?

Comment: Isn't there a way to write all cookies to localhost? And read them across all domains/subdomains?

Comment: The docs for PHP's `setcookie` say `Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'.` which is what you're looking for. Perhaps this is the way to go.

Comment: thanks, I'll use it. Seems like the best idea. Could you tell me one more thing? If this a good idea for logging in users? Any disadvantages over using _SESSION like users having cookies disabled or something?

Comment: generally `$_SESSION` variables use cookies to associate data with a user, so there isn't really a difference there